# Convert tensor of integers to binary tensor with 1 only at that index

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Is there a pain free to convert a tensor of integers to a binary tensor with 1 only at that integers index in pytorch?

e.g.

```
tensor([[1,3,2,6]])
```

would become

```
tensor([[0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
        [0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,1]])
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: See [How much research?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).  Try the phrase "one-hot encoding".

Answer (score 1):

```
t = tensor([[1,3,2,6]])

rows = t.shape[1]
cols = t.max() + 1

output = torch.zeros(rows, cols) # initializes zeros array of desired dimensions
output[list(range(rows)), t.tolist()] = 1 # sets cells to 1
```

To clarify the last operation, you can pass in a list of the row numbers and column numbers, and it will set all those elements to the value after the equal.
So in our case we want to set the following locations to 1:

```
(0,1), (1,3), (2,2), (3,6)
```

Which we'd represent as:

```
output[[0,1,2,3], [1,3,2,6]] = 1
```

And you'll see that those lists line up with **a)** an increasing list up to the total row count, and **b)** our original tensor